An old cartoon(?) about Martians being flat (2D) so we can't see them through telescope
When I was a kid (in late 80s) I saw once on the TV a cartoon (or maybe a movie for children) where the idea of Martians being flat was introduced. So this is why we can't see them through the telescope: they are just 2D and we need to be close to the Mars to see them from above.
That was on the Eastern Europe TV so that can be production from anywhere, USSR, Hungary, Czechoslovakia, Bulgaria? No idea.
That is one of the mysteries of my childhood. I wonder now if that is more the Martians themselves or the movie?
Anyone remember that maybe? Or was I dreaming and just possessed the secret of life on Mars?

Has somewhat similar feel to book Flat Land.  About 2 dimensional shapes and they cant see from their point of view what shape each person is because everything is a line from their perspective.  They mentioned it in The Orville TV show.
